# Xampp Is Messing Up?

Tags: xampp

First Apache wouldn't work with me so I had to change the port number which fixed everything so that is good, but then I went online and found this

> "Start Apache and MySQL and go to localhost in your browser (on the same machine as your server). If this is your first time browsing the local site, you should now see a webpage with the XAMPP logo and a choice of languages. Click on your preferred language."

When I type in localhost:8080 (Apache port), it comes up this [image] I have no clue how to make it so I'm taken to the XAMPP Logo where the languages are. -.- Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Just create a sample html page in htdocs of your apache folder and try to access it in browser.
If you name it is as index.html, you just have to write localhost in the browser or localhost/.html

This will make sure your server is working.

And in cmd prompt run mysql -u -p status to check the status of mysql that will check whether mysql is working or not.

Comment: Can you explain more? How do I create a sample html? @shreshta bm

Comment: just open a new text file, type in something like. <html> <h1> Hello World</h1> </html> and save it as index.html. Then try hit localhost in your browser.